# I've never thought of that [before]

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Do these two sentences have the same meaning?

> I've never thought of that.

> I've never thought of that before.

To me, the first means I've never thought of that, and implies I still don't think of it now.

The second means I've never thought of that before now, and implies there's a change, that now I begin to think of it.

To answer this question: *what'll you do in five years*, what would you say? 1 or 2?

1. I've never thought of that.
2. I've never thought of that before

Answer (score 1):

If we consider the *MOST PRECISE* meaning of this sentence, **you are correct**. *"Before"* means that in this moment, one has indeed thought of it and thus bringing about a change.

However, in everyday language and even in formal writings, both sentences are used very much interchangeably. If anything, "before" is just for **emphasis** that the thought has never crossed one's mind.